# Linq - optimize/correct my query

Tags: c#, linq

I have this linq query (not sure if its correct) but what I want is:

Get me all my company offices (that are related to my company e.g. companyid == mycompanyid)
that have declared they have postcode "cv", return back only offices. (code for clarity)

```
var offices = from office in _readOnlySession.All<Office>()
.GetMyOffices(_userSession) //filter out my offices using extension method
let postcodes = _readOnlySession.All<OfficePostCode>().Where(x => x.OfficeID == office.OfficeID)
                .Join(_readOnlySession.All<PostCodeDistrict>().Where(r=> r.Region.ToLower().StartsWith("cv".ToLower())),
                          x => x.PostCodeID,
                          y => y.PostCodeID,
                          (x, y) => new { Region = y.Region })
where postcodes.Any()
select new { office.OfficeID, office.Name };
```

Question: how can I make this all a query method, a more optimized/correct query method?

*Note: "cv" is going to be a variable passed into the method - kinda hardcoded to illustrate my example*

Update:

```
    IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class, new();

    public IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        return GetTable<T>().AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't .All<T> take a Func<T, bool> as a parameter and return a bool, not an enumerable?  It doesn't look like that code would compile.

Comment: @Bodrick - it compiles and works!

Comment: I guess you're using some extension method there then.  What type is _readOnlySession? Does .All<T>() just return all objects from that collection of the given type?

Comment: @Bodrick - yes, it returns a list of object of that type...

Comment: Is `All` a custom extension method? because it sounds like it's doing what `OfType<T>()` does.

Comment: @weston - yes, see above - my question is more about getting back offices that have declared they have a certain postcode region...

Comment: Sorry, what kind of session is this. Only if it's SQL server, I'd personally see what kind of query it's translating to and analyse the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed that `OfficePostCode` and `Office` both have `PostCodeID` properties, you might need to change the last `.Where()` clause to fit the properties you have.  This should do what you want though, and IMO is a bit easier to read.

```
public IEnumerable<Office> GetOffices (string postCode)
{
    List<Office> myOffices = _readOnlySession.All<Office> ()
        .GetMyOffices (_userSession)
        .ToList (); // Get all the offices you are interested in.


    List<OfficePostCode> postCodeDistricts = _readOnlySession
        .All<OfficePostCode> ()
        .Where (x => x.Region.StartsWith (postCode, true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        .ToList (); // A list of OfficePostCodes with the specified region.

    // Using the 3 parameter overload for StartsWith lets you specify a case invariant comparison,
    // which saves you from having to do .ToLower().

    return myOffices.Where (o => postCodeDistricts.Any (pcd => o.PostCodeID == pcd.PostCodeID));
}
```

Of course, you can compact this down by removing the intermediate variables,  but I personally find it clearer this way.  It makes debugging easier as well, as you can put breakpoints on the intermediate variables.

Comment: If that works it looks more efficient. There are no anonymous objects being created and does away with the join. Plus is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be OK. Only what can but also cannot work better is to execute *let postcodes* part without OfficeID condition before main query and then use it in main query like:

```
where postcodes.Any(pc => pc.OfficeID == office.OfficeID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
var offices = _readOnlySession.All<Office>()
    .GetMyOffices(_userSession) //filter out my offices using extension method
    .Where(office => office.PostCodes.Any(pc => pc.District.Region.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith("CV")));
```